# Equivalence between non-singular vector field without periodic orbits and the irrational flow on a torus.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm reading the book "The dynamics of vector Fields in dimension 3 - Matthias Moreno and Siddhartha Bhattacharya "

On page 6 the authors enunciate the following theorem:

> **Theorem:(Poincaré, Denjoy:)** Every non-singular $\mathcal{C}^2$ vector field on a compact surface
>   that has no periodic orbits is topologically equivalent to a linear
>   flow on a torus with the irrational slope.

An interesting comment is that this result is not true for $\mathcal{C}^1$ vector
fields.

I searched for this result on the Internet but I didn't find any book/paper that demonstrates the above theorem.

Does anyone know how to prove this or can give me a reference where I can learn the proof of the theorem?

**N.B.** I only need to know how to demonstrate the theorem when the vector field is on $\mathbb{T}^2$.

Comment: Note that the surface must be the torus, otherwise the vector field must vanish (Lefschetz), Then see Denjoy's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%27s_theorem_on_rotation_number. I guess a very rough idea would be "take a circular Poincaré section, apply Denjoy's theorem, then extend the conjugation to the whole torus".

Comment: @D.Thomine When a vector field on $\mathbb{T}^2$ has no periodic orbits and singular points is always possible to "take a circular Poincaré Section"? Do you have any reference where can I learn such result? I'm asking this because the existence of this special section is related to another problem that I'm facing.

Comment: See, e.g. Katok and Hasselblatt [Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_the_Modern_Theory_of_Dyn.html?id=9nL7ZX8Djp4C&redir_esc=y), pp. 457-458.

Comment: @user539887 thx for this reference, you help me a lot (the section that you recommended me to read has awesome theorems!).

Comment: @user539887 just confirming ... Do you know if we can guarantee that the equivalence is a $\mathcal{C}^1$-equivalence? (I think that we can't guarantee such regularity of the equivalence)

Comment: I don't know ... Perhaps you could try asking a new question?